# If the Model should contain all of the business logic, what is the best way to call class methods in the Model? (more inside)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Alright, so I have always read that in ASP.NET MVC one should always put the business logic in the model.  So let's say I have this model class:

```
public class CarModel
{
        [Display(Name = "Car Manufacturer")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Car Manufacturer is required")]
        public string CarManufacturer { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Car Year")]
        public int CarYear{ get; set; }
}
```

How would I add a method to this model and then run the method on an instance of this model?  What I mean is lets say I have a new instance like this:

```
CarModel MyCar = new CarModel();
```

How would I add a method to this model and then run the method on my new MyCar instance of the model?  Could I do something like:

```
MyCar.MyModelMethod();
```

If so, how would I code the model method to allow for this sort of calling?

Comment: Have you tried the way to posted?

Comment: "one should always put the business logic in the model"   I would NEVER do that.  I would write "other classes" the utilize the models.....what happens when 4 "models" are needed to make a business decision, where are you going to put it?

Comment: You would probably actually not code this in the model, but use extensions. Also one pitfall to watch out for is modifying EF's generated POCO classes, you should either abstract that model into persistant classes or just operate on viewmodels used for your views. And as for putting business logic in the model (didn't see that a minute ago) don't. It's fine to put it in your controllers.

Comment: It's not "fine" to put business logic in your controllers. Controllers should only be responsible for wiring up the view; business logic belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two aspects to this. There's the MVC *pattern* and then there's ASP.NET MVC, the framework, which implements the MVC pattern to a greater or lesser degree.

In MVC, the Model is the haven of all business logic. However, ASP.NET MVC does not truly have a concept of a Model. The classes that are often referred to as "Models" are actually just entities, your POCOs that are tied to database tables. These are poor excuses for MVC-style Models, which is why most developers supplement them with two other concepts: view models and a data access layer or DAL.

View models are just classes, but specifically, they're classes that you craft specifically to serve the purposes of one or more views. They'll often represent some entity class, but they'll have other properties and methods that would be inappropriate to add to an entity class. In your actions, you'd map your entities to/from these view models, creating a separation of concerns: the entity can concern itself only with the needs of the database and the view model can concern itself only with the needs of the view.

The DAL is where you would have repository or service classes. These would hold the logic specific to working with your entity classes. The entity just holds the data, whereas your DAL determines how that data is retrieved, saved, etc.

Together these three (entities, view models, and repositories/services) constitute the MVC Model.